# .html('') doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am trying to remove an object with jquery using `.html('')` in my component.
It's works in almost browsers, but in Safari doesn't work.
why this happen?

Comment: Please post a complete example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to take an element out of the DOM, use [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), don't use `.html("")`.

If you want to make the element empty, use [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

Also, to answer your question, you probably have some bug in your code because `.html('')` works on my Safari, tested on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYfUm/).